# What is wrong with this code - 'ArgOutValueArray(int (__gc* __nogc& aRef) __gc[] )'

Tags: visual-c++, mscorlib

We have a VC++ project for CLR which is compiling properly in VS 2012. But getting the following exception during runtime:

"Could not load type 'System.Int32[]&' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'"

Following is the code:

---

```
// ClassLibrary1.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
 using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1 {

 //template <typename T>
     class ArgOutValueArray 
    {
     public:
         ArgOutValueArray(int (__gc* __nogc& aRef) __gc[] )
         {
             //(*x)[0] = 100;
         }

       };


 public __gc class Class1
  {

   public:

              static void f1([Out] int (*x) __gc[])
               {
                     f2(x);
               }

     static void f2([Out] int (*x) __gc[])
      {
        ArgOutValueArray arg_xeqp(x); // Getting the exception at this line.
      }

 };
 }
```

---

Comment: What is `ArgOutValueArray`? Is that what's throwing the exception? You are using the old MC++ syntax. Have you considered moving to C++/CLI?

Comment: "ArgOutValueArray" is a class with a contructor as mentioned in the code. How to convert "ArgOutValueArray(int (__gc* __nogc& aRef) __gc[] )" to new syntax?

Comment: Ugh, that makes my eyes bleed.  You could at least have indented it properly.  Use a decompiler to try to make sense of it.  Or just throw it away and rewrite.